# What do we call these "transport frames made of wood" (обрешетки in Russian)

Tags: terminology, transportation

I'm translating a document in which there is a mention of **обрешетки** used for preparing goods (medical equipment of large size) for shipment. This term derives from reshetka (решетка) - lattice, and means "custom-made frame of wooden planks built around a load destined for shipping". It's kind of a rough crate built around the product intended for shipping, not pre-made.

I wonder what the proper term in English might be. Multitran [provides a long list of options](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0), but without describing them much, so it's hard to distinguish.

There's a whole [National Standard document in Russian](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/1200011144) that describes how these "frames" must be built, with many pictures. However, it provides the wrong translation there in English: "roof boarding" (because the same Russian term is also used for roof lattice).

[image]
[image]

I'm submitting my translation in an hour, so I'll stick with descriptive "wooden frames" but I'd be glad to learn the formal term if it exists.

Comment: A framed pallet ? or  reinforced pallet?

Comment: This is ‘crate framing’

Comment: +1 Crate Frame is what I’ve heard these called before but I don’t have a formal reference for this - only anecdotal, so not posting as a full answer.

Comment: "Roof boarding" is definitely the wrong translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The English term for this is definitely ***crate***.

Comment: I would argue crates are generally fully enclosed.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! So even when they are not premade, but instead are built around a load to be shipped, they are crates. Curious how in Russian there are two terms and in English there's one

Comment: @morbo Often they are, but they don't have to be. I looked up several dictionary definitions, and only one mentioned a fully enclosed box.

Comment: @CopperKettle Yes, most definitely! Most crates that I have seen when working in several industries were custom-made from wood.